# How to mock AWSXRay in order to test Java code in Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, aws-xray

I have a code that begins the subsegment.
Subsegment subsegment = AWSXRay.beginSubsegment("makeHTTPCall function");

So I tried mocking it out as Mockito.mock(AWSXRay): I see an exception below: what is wrong here?
com.amazonaws.xray.exceptions.SegmentNotFoundException: Failed to begin subsegment named 'makeHTTPCall function': segment cannot be found.
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at com.amazonaws.xray.strategy.RuntimeErrorContextMissingStrategy.contextMissing(RuntimeErrorContextMissingStrategy.java:32)
at com.amazonaws.xray.contexts.ThreadLocalSegmentContext.beginSubsegment(ThreadLocalSegmentContext.java:40)
at com.amazonaws.xray.AWSXRayRecorder.beginSubsegment(AWSXRayRecorder.java:616)
at com.amazonaws.xray.AWSXRay.beginSubsegment(AWSXRay.java:121)
at com.it.TestAwsXrayHandlerRefactored.makeHTTPCall(TestAwsXrayHandlerRefactored.java:87)
at com.it.TestAwsXrayHandlerRefactored.handleRequest(TestAwsXrayHandlerRefactored.java:51)
at com.learnit.TestAwsXrayHandlerRefactoredTest.testHandleRequest(TestAwsXrayHandlerRefactoredTest.java:58)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error, you can simply begin a segment with `AWSXRay.beginSegment("test")` in your JUnit `BeforeEach` statement, and then clear your trace context in the JUnit `AfterEach` statement with `AWSXRay.clearTraceContext()`.

Alternatively, you can start a segment in each unit test and set configure your X-Ray recorder to have no-op behavior in your `Before` statement as we do: https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-java/blob/9b724620c126b05313f4c97d18853bbb469e9ba5/aws-xray-recorder-sdk-apache-http/src/test/java/com/amazonaws/xray/proxies/apache/http/TracedResponseHandlerTest.java#L37

But that's probably a more complex option.